# PyTrends Api Not giving Same Results On google Colab after each Runtime Start

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, google-trends

I am using pytrends library in google colab, the problem is, whenever I restart my runtime the results are different. Here is my code

```
!pip install pytrends
```

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

wom = 'today 1-m'
geo = 'GB'
key_word = '401k'
pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US',tz=-360)
pytrend.build_payload([key_word], timeframe=wom, geo=geo)
wtrends = pytrend.interest_over_time()
print(wtrends)
```

This code always give me same results when I run it on my local machine using anaconda. You can verify the results by going to the google trends website and by selecting the region to United Kindom.